# Wrong color on CAGradient applied to UITextView

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uitextview, cagradientlayer

I'm creating an iOS7 app and I have an `UITextView` inside a `UITableView` cell with a `CAGradient` applied to it. If I use different colors from `clearColor` works fine, but if I use `clearColor` as one of the colors for the gradient it turns out to be gray...

This is my code. `theContent` is my `UITextView`.

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = theContent.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];
[theContent.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:100];
```

And this is the final (wrong) result...

[image]

How can I fix this to have a `clearColor` to `whiteColor` gradient???

Comment: and... what is your question?

Comment: You're right, let me change my question :-)

Comment: what does it happen if you use either `[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.f alpha:0.f]` or `[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:0.f]` instead of the `clearColor`?

Comment: `[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:0.f]` worked. Add it as answer and I'll give you proper acceptance :P Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it may help on you if you try to use

```
[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:0.f];
```

instead of the `clearColor` for the white tone.